# Newenvironment with path name as variable

Tags: environments, paths

I am currently working on a larger project, with several chapters. All of them are in folders `chapter<chapternumber>`. Each of the folders has a subfolder `images`, for images. I have to put them all in an appendix at the end of the document. So I thought I made myself a new environment `appfig` that saves me some work:

```
\newenvironment{appfig}[3]
{
\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\input{chapter#1/image/#2}
\caption{#3}
\label{fig:#2}
\end{figure}
}
```

where `#1`would be the corresponding chapter, `#2`the name of the image and `#3`the caption of the image.
However, I get the errors

```
Runaway argument?
{chapter4,htb_angle_theory,htb/image/
! Paragraph ended before \@iinput was complete.
<to be read again> 
\par 
l.24 

Runaway argument?
{
! Paragraph ended before \caption@prepareanchor was complete.
<to be read again> 
               \par 
l.24 

Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup.
\@caption ...\else \caption@prepareanchor {#1}{#2}
                           \memcaptioninfo {#1}    {\csna...     
l.24
```

and some more of this kind.
I called the environment on line 22 with `\appfig{4,imagename.tex,some caption}`.

I do this inside the appendix:

```
\chapter*{Appendix}
\pagenumbering{Roman}
\setcounter{page}{1}
\appfig{4,htb_angle_theory,htb}
```

Is there a way I can make clear that `#1`has to be added to the filepath as just this number?

EDIT:

I should have mentioned that I intend to use this function only for pgf-plots. That's why I have `\input{}` in the `figure`-environment.
When I use the normal figure environment, everything works fine.

Comment: the error you describe is unrelated to the code you post (which has other issues such as missing `%` and the use of `[h]`)  please always post a complete example that can be run to show the problem.

Comment: how does you `#1` look like ? please add complete example.

Comment: also it is useful to post the entire error message, from `!` to `?` copied from the log file to a code section, so line breaks are preserved

Answer (score 1):

The environment is defined with *three* arguments:

```
\newenvironment{appfig}[3]{...}{...}
```

The end part is missing (TeX takes `\par` from the following empty line).

It is used as command with *one* argument:

```
\appfig{4,htb_angle_theory,htb}
```

This is fixed by using `\newcommand`:

```
\newcommand{\appfig}[3]{...}
```

and and calling the command with *three* arguments:

```
\appfig{4}{htb_angle_theory}{htb}
```

If the appendix does not contain text, then using `minipage` with `\captionof{figure}{#3}` of package `capt-of` or `caption` would be an alternative to environment `figure`, because floating environments do not make much sense in this case.

BTW, `\pagenumbering` already resets the page number to one.